# How to make a Power BI DAX measure apply to rows individually?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of Projects and a table of Weeks (representing the number of weeks from today)

Trying to use this measure to spread the value of each project over the project's duration:

```
RevenuebyWeek= 

IF(
        
    MAX('Table'[InForecast]) = 1 &&
    SUMX('Table','Table'[Start])<=TODAY()+(max(Weeks[WeekRef])*7) &&
    TODAY()+(MAX(Weeks[WeekRef])*7)<sumx('Table','Table'[Finish]),
    
    sumx('Table','Table'[RevenueBacklog])/sumx('Table','Table'[Weeks]),0
)
```

This works at the project level, but not once you try to aggregate these values, see screenshot below.

Is this because the measure is applying to all projects collectively? How do I make it apply to projects individually?

[image: table 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMX does work by row, I just needed to re-word the IF statement into a FILTER within the SUMX. Like this:

```
RevenueByWeek= 

SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'Table', 
        'Table'[InForecast] = 1 &&
            'Table'[Start] <=TODAY()+(SELECTEDVALUE(Weeks[WeekRef])*7) &&
            TODAY()+(SELECTEDVALUE(Weeks[WeekRef])*7)<'Table'[Finish]
    ),
    'Table'[RevenueBacklog] / 'Table'[Weeks]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you apply the measure to all projects.

```
SUMX('Table','Table'[Start])<=TODAY()+(max(Weeks[WeekRef])*7)

SUMX('Table','Table'[Start]) -- seems it can be the unbeatable Value when aggregating
```

Create 2 measures - one for "Hasonevalue" and other for your aggrigation and use a "Switch" or IF

Comment: The problem is that the aggregation measure still needs to evaluate each row individually to see if it has a value, otherwise the total is not correct. If you could do a For Each on the rows that would be great but seems this isn't an option in DAX.

Comment: If you Filter your Table like `VAR filtered =Filter( 'Table','Table'[InForecast]=1, 'Table'[Start])<=TODAY()+(max(Weeks[WeekRef])*7),TODAY()+(MAX(Weeks[WeekRef])*7)<sumx('Table','Table'[Finish]))` and then you `SUMX(filtered,'Table'[RevenueBacklog])...`  It'd difficult to give an advice, but I belive it should be a solution for you. Function like SUMX scanns tables row by row, you just need to create a proper table )